Disable "Eject" option of an USB drive
I am looking for options to stop the user from ejecting a USB drive.
They don't have physical access to it, but nothing stops them from clicking "Eject" in File Explorer or down at the taskbar. I have a couple of ideas, but can't find a good solution to any of them:

Remove the "Eject" option from Windows altogether

Stop USB drives from showing in the Explorer, but in a way I could still read its files in my program

Set USB drive's attributes in a way it shows as a basic partition and not a removable one

Leave the "Eject" option alone, and instead somehow force Windows to re-scan drives and mount all drives in ejected state


I'm on Windows 10/11.
The 3rd option is doable I think using a program bootit from Lexar- which I'm researching now, not sure if it's going to work the I want it, but will try it anyway.
The 4th can be done but in Windows 11 I can't get those solution to work, but I just found that if I manually disable/enable the drive in Device Manager it will mount itself back, but I need to figure out how to do it with a script, and I think I will need to know the device ID somehow... Didn't find any built-in options.
This drive is plugged in once and serves a purpose of a machine ID, never unplugged

Besides these ideas, have you done any research to see which of these are possible, or whether there's a built-in/official option to do this? Will staff need to ever insert and and eject USB drives at all, or should this be entirely disabled on the computers?

Info like that should be added to the question itself because it is helpful to better understanding your situation. However, we need the answer to my second question too: do staff need to connect/disconnect other USB drives, or, to put it another way, is disabling this notification system-wide, for all removable devices, an acceptable solution?

"I'm on Windows 10/11" Does this computer run Windows 10 or 11? That may be important to find a solution.

I believe @music2myear is referring to other USB drives, not the one hidden inside the machine. Do staff need to connect/disconnect other USB drives, or is the hidden one the only one they'll ever be using on that machine?

If the device is in the machine and the case is locked, can't you just hide the drive from display and explorer and leave it at that? Are you afraid the user is going to read the files on the USB? If so, just leaving them available is totally unacceptable

How often does the machine ID device need to be read? If just at boot time, then a solution is easy.

Can't you put a unique ID in the TPM module? Then you could throw away all the usb sticks.

@W.Donald please add this and other information to your question. A major part of getting good answers is having a complete question, and the questions' we've asked have been about completing the information that your question needs. Please make frequent use of the EDIT button.

Please do not vandalise your question.
